# Can I use two level of variable length argument functions...?

Tags: c, function, variables, arguments, variadic-functions

I have one problem with variable length argument debug log print function. I will just simulate the code here.

```
void SecondPrint(int level, const char* format,...)
{
   //Printing the log here
   va_list arg;
   va_start(arg, format);
   vprintf(format, arg);
   va_end(arg);   
}

void FirstPrint(int level, const char* format,...)
{
   SecondPrint(level,format);
}

void main()
{
   int level = 100;
   FirstPrintf("Log level = %d message = %s \n",level,"Error message");
}
```

"SecondPrint" is supposed to print "100 Error message" as expected, But its not printing like that its printing " Error message".

I am not getting whats wrong with this one. I am suspecting the way of calling "SecondPrint" from "FirstPrint" function. FirstPrint is receiving remaining arguments through ... but its invoking SecondPrint with level and format arguments.

I can't use SecondPrint from main directly. **I have to use FirstPrint and FirstPrint has to call SecondPrint to print the log**. So how can I achieve this one.. I thought to use **VA_ARGS** but it is for only macro definitions not in function definition.

And one more thing **I can't do like **#define FirstPrint(a,b,...) SecondPrint(a,b,...)****

any help is highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

C varargs are not designed to be passed more than one level; the kind of necessary stack manipulation required is too deep for the language.  Typically, in a case like this, you would have a version of `SecondPrint` analagous to `vprintf` -- `SecondPrintV` or similar, and you would have `FirstPrint` invoke `SecondPrintV` after extracting the varargs, rather than invoking `SecondPrint` directly (and, for consistency, usually have `SecondPrint` invoke `SecondPrintV` internally).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `va_list` to `SecondPrint`, so it can access the arguments to `FirstPrint`

```
void SecondPrint(int level, const char* format, va_list args)
{
   //Printing the log here
   vprintf(format, arg);
}

void FirstPrint(int level, const char* format,...)
{
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   SecondPrint(level, format, args);
   va_end(args);
}

void main()
{
   int level = 100;
   FirstPrintf("Log level = %d message = %s \n",level,"Error message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do it in specific platform-specific ways, or (since the arguments are exactly the same in the same order) use assembly to "replace" the current function frame with the function to call. GCC also has [an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html) to do it with the `__builtin_apply_args()` and `__builtin_apply()` functions (although you must somehow figure out how to compute the size of the stack argument data).